# CAML Join for retrieving FieldLeafRef

Tags: javascript, caml, client-object-model

I'va a custom list which contains a lookup field to a document library. Now I need to retrieve all items from this list with the corresponding file name from the document library with Javascript CSOM.

It seems like I can make a join for retrieving the title field, but I get an error as soon as I try to retrieve the FileLeafRef field (Value does not fall withing the expected range).

Here the CAML query which I use:

```
<View>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="myLookupField" />
    <FieldRef Name="DocTitle" />
    <FieldRef Name="DocName" />
  </ViewFields>
  <ProjectedFields>
    <Field Name="DocTitle" Type="Lookup" List="myDocumentLibrary" ShowField="Title" />
    <Field Name="DocName" Type="Lookup" List="myDocumentLibrary" ShowField="FileLeafRef" />
  </ProjectedFields>
  <Joins>
    <Join Type="Left" ListAlias="myDocumentLibrary">
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="myLookupField" RefType="Id" />
        <FieldRef List="myDocumentLibrary" Name="Id" />
      </Eq>
    </Join>
  </Joins>
</View>
```

If I remove FileLeafRef from the query it works. Any idea what's the error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume my problem might be that the type of the FileLeafRef column (File) is not supported in CAML joins as noted here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539975%28v=office.14%29.aspx

```
Only the following types of fields can be included in a ProjectedFields element:
    Calculated (treated as plain text)
    ContentTypeId
    Counter
    Currency
    DateTime
    Guid
    Integer
    Note (one-line only)
    Number
    Text
```